# parse nested conditional statements

Tags: python, regex, conditional-compilation

I need to parse a file that contains conditional statements, sometimes nested inside one another.

I have a file that stores configuration data but the configuration data is slightly different depending on user defined options. I can deal with the conditional statements, they're all just booleans with no operations but I don't know how to recursively evaluate the nested conditionals. For instance, a piece of the file might look like:

```
...
#if CELSIUS
    #if FROM_KELVIN ; this is a comment about converting kelvin to celsius.
        temp_conversion = 1, 273
    #else
        temp_conversion = 0.556, -32
    #endif
#else
    #if FROM_KELVIN
        temp_conversion = 1.8, -255.3
    #else
        temp_conversion = 1.8, 17.778
    #endif
#endif
...
```

... Also, some conditionals don't have an `#else` statement, just `#if CONDITION statement(s) #endif`.

I realize that this could be easy if the file were just written in XML or something else with a nice parser to begin with, but this is what I have to work with so I'm wondering if there's any relatively simple way to parse this file. It's similar to parenthesis matching so I imagine there would be some module for it but I haven't found anything.

I'm working in python but I can switch for this function if it's easier to solve this in another language.

Comment: Is there a name or a standard for this format? And how/where are constants like FROM_KELVIN defined? Finally, why are there two values for each assignment- should it assign a tuple to `temp_conversion`?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea, but you can convert this code to Python code with a few regex substitutions (it took four for me) and just evaluate it in a sandboxed environment.

Comment: @DavidRobinson The format doesn't have a standard that I'm aware of, I'm trying to make a small open source program that will be compatible with legacy formats used by an existing proprietary application and this is the format they use.Dealing with the conditions and statements isn't a problem, I'll just keep a dictionary of booleans for the conditions and I already have a regex parser for the temp_conversion stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of the conditions are binary and I know the values of all of them in advance (no need to evaluate them in order in order like a programming language), i was able to do it with a regular expression. This works better for me. It finds the lowest level conditionals (ones with no nested conditions), evaluates them and replaces them with the correct contents. Then repeats for the higher level conditionals and so on.

```
import re

conditions = ['CELSIUS', 'FROM_KELVIN']

def eval_conditional(matchobj):
    statement = matchobj.groups()[1].split('#else')
    statement.append('') # in case there was no else statement
    if matchobj.groups()[0] in conditions: return statement[0]
    else: return statement[1]

def parse(text):
    pattern = r'#if\s*(\S*)\s*((?:.(?!#if|#endif))*.)#endif'
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
    while True:
        if not regex.search(text): break
        text = regex.sub(eval_conditional, text)
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()
    g = ''.join([x.split(';')[0] for x in i if x.strip()])
    o = parse(g)
    open('output.txt', 'w').write(o)
```

Given the input in the original post, it outputs:

```
...
        temp_conversion = 1, 273

...
```

which is what I need. Thanks to everyone for their responses, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple recursive parser for this syntax:

```
def parse(lines):
    result = []
    while lines:
        if lines[0].startswith('#if'):
            block = [lines.pop(0).split()[1], parse(lines)]
            if lines[0].startswith('#else'):
                lines.pop(0)
                block.append(parse(lines))
            lines.pop(0) #endif
            result.append(block)
        elif not lines[0].startswith(('#else', '#endif')):
            result.append(lines.pop(0))
        else:
            break
    return result

tree = parse([x.strip() for x in your_code.splitlines() if x.strip()])
```

From your example it creates the following tree structure:

```
[['CELSIUS',
  [['FROM_KELVIN',
    ['temp_conversion = 1, 273'],
    ['temp_conversion = 0.556, -32']]],
  [['FROM_KELVIN',
    ['temp_conversion = 1.8, -255.3'],
    ['temp_conversion = 1.8, 17.778']]]]]
```

which should be easy to evaluate.

For more advanced parsing consider one of many [parsing tools](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) available for Python.

Comment: Thanks! That helps but the file has multiple conditionals and this function would lump them all in to the same structure. Also, it would be nice if the code could be awkwardly formed without breaking the parser, this code expects that everything is nicely split by linebreaks and so on. Maybe a parser is the way to go, it looks like YAPPS (from the link you posted) could work nicely for this.